# Use vue.js component to count up a data value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using **vue.js** and try to recreate the ["Listening to Events"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) example. They use the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="example-1">
  <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
  <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
    data: {
    counter: 0
  }
})
```

I want to do the same, but as its something I will do more often I want to create a component:

HTML

```
<div id="example-1">
  <counterButton></counterButton>
  <p>The button above has been clicked {{ counter }} times.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('counterButton', {
  template: '<button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>'
})

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
    data: {
    counter: 0
  }
})
```

This does not seem to be working, while I receive the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "nextPage" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
> data properties in the data option.

As I am not used to javascript too much, I am simply not able to understand the error. I guess I have to somehow "link" the `data` value to my component?

Comment: This warning about something else, there is no `nextPage` property on your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component should be called like below.

```
<counter-button></counter-button>
```

This will fix the warning and the button will appear. However, your counter will not change (not the way you are expecting it at least).

**Reason**

This is because now a button is a standalone component and it does not know about the counter of the parent component.

I recommend to take a look at the official documentation of VueJs about the components and they have a nice example of a [counter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

**Side note**:

If you wish to reuse one button at multiple components to increase only one counter you will have to implement [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#ad) or use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). These are, however, a bit advanced topics and you should cover the basics first.